# How to change the cursor when it hover overs a Google maps polyline from being a hand

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When you hover over a polyline in Google Maps (Chrome) the cursor changes to a hand. This is undesirable for me as it's causing flickering between the default map cursor and the hand cursor (the polyline moves as the mouse moves).

I tried this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(temp_polyline, 'mouseover', function(e) {
                map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'crosshair'});
                map.setOptions({draggingCursor:'crosshair'});
            });
```

But the crosshair cursor is still only visible when the cursor is not hovering over a polyline

Answer (score 1):

Set the "clickable" option of the polyline to false, then it shows only the crosshair cursor which is set in the code of my question and no longer shows the "hand". The hand only appears to show that the polyline is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code to the following and let me know how it works:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(e) {
            map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'crosshair'});
        });
```

**EDIT:**

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591227/4667831) to use a combination of CSS and JS to change the default cursor

Comment: I can change the cursor on the map. Just not over the polyline.

Comment: I found a useful link that will solve your problem, its under the edit

Answer (score 0):

I worked out this to be doing the job:

```
map.addListener("mousemove", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
  map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'crosshair'});
});
```